# Asynchronous Programming with c# - async , await and Task.Run

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncWithWait();
        //Console.WriteLine(s.Result);
        Task.Run(() => AsyncWithOutWait());
        Console.WriteLine("Main End");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static void AsyncWithOutWait()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncWithOutWait");
    }

    public static async Task AsyncWithWait()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncWithWait");
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between the way AsyncWithWait and AsyncWithOutWait in the above implementation?

The output is as expected but I would like to know the proper way to implement Asynchronous programming.

**Output**

```
Main End
AsyncWithOutWait
AsyncWithWait
```

Comment: yes there is difference, first is blocking call while second is not

Comment: @EhsanSajjad _"first is blocking call"_ - incorrect.  `AsyncWithWait()` returns a `Task` that actually isn't awaited.  There is a risk that the program can terminate if the user presses a key within 5 seconds

Comment: what i meant was `Thread.Sleep` will block the call , while using `async` and `await` with `Task.Delay` wouldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the way AsyncWithWait and AsyncWithOutWait in the above implementation?

`AsyncWithWait` doesn't block a thread just waiting for the time period; `AsyncWithOutWait` does.

> The output is as expected but I would like to know the proper way to implement Asynchronous programming.

Use `async` and `await`. To understand more how it works, read my [intro to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post.

Comment: Great Intro!  Contains some nice examples.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by blocks the thread? As far my understanding, the main method writes to the console first "Main End". If this thread is blocked, the "Main End" would have been written only after "AsyncWithOutWait". Please correct me.

Comment: @TechJerk: `Task.Run` runs `AsyncWithOutWait` on a thread pool thread. `AsyncWithOutWait` blocks that thread pool thread.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, AsyncWithOutWait is a synchronous method(the lines in this method will be executed synchronously) called asynchronously?. Assume if I want to write to a file(void method) which could take longer time, if I go with AsyncWithOutWait, still it is prefect? because I don't need any return from Write file operation?

Comment: @TechJerk: `AsyncWithOutWait` is a synchronous method executed on a background thread. This is an acceptable technique for UI apps, but not for server apps (e.g., ASP.NET). Whether you need a return value or not is immaterial.